# Method for having two parallel inheritence structures interact across levels

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, interface

I have an issue where I have a set of objects in the business layer that have an inheritance structure between them and I also have a set of DAL objects that back them which have a roughly parallel inheritance structure.  The problem I have encountered is that the DAL type must be understood on multiple levels of the BOL inheritance, for example, a base business object must be able to access base DAL object properties, however the same property must provide the specific instance later.

Since C# doesn't support return covariance, I'm not able to simply use a more specific type in an override declaration.  I'm also not able to use generics as I would have to do a concrete specification of the type to make use of it and that breaks further inheritance for the same return covariance reason.  The only solution I've been able to come up with so far seems very scary so I wanted to post it here for feedback or alternate ideas.

It seems this can be dealt with by defining a generic interface `IHasDal<TDalType>`.  I can then specify that the `BOLBase : IHasDal<BaseDAL>`.  This then requires an implementation of the .Dal property on BOLBase.  For BolChild, it is declared as `BOLChild : BOLBase, IHasDal<ChildDAL>` and then specifies a `.Dal` property that is of type `ChildDAL`.  While these two commands are unrelated and specific to the level of the class they reside within, I linked them by having a private field in `BOLBase` of type `BaseDAL`.  I can then cast it via AS for each child property implementation.

In theory it seems like this should give me what I'm looking for with minimal issues.  It will be available for either an object implementing an `IHasDal` of whatever type I specify or for any given `BOLBase` derived class.  It still feels ugly since it appears to be effectively relying on method hiding, but I can't think of anything better.

```
public interface IHasDal<TDalType>
    where TDalType : BaseDal
{
    TDalType Dal { get; set; }
}

public class BaseDal
{
}

public class BaseEntity : IHasDal<BaseDal>
{
    protected BaseDal _dal;

    public BaseDal Dal
    {
        get
        {
            return (BaseDal)_dal;
        }
        set
        {
            _dal = value;
        }
    }
}

public class ChildDal : BaseDal
{
}

public class ChildEntity : BaseEntity, IHasDal<ChildDal>
{
    public ChildDal Dal
    {
        get
        {
            return this._dal as ChildDal;
        }
        set
        {
            this._dal = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a better fit on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Possibly, but I couldn't find anything else related to the question either.  I'm not sure that the fact I had one possible solution means I have the best answer to the original question.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the Repository pattern. http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

Comment: @PeterRitchie - We are actually using the Repository pattern already, the actual DAL object being described is actually an object which is populated by the repository and handed off to be used by the business object.  It's a limitation we are currently stuck with for now.

Comment: It's not clear based on your post *why* a domain object (BaseEntity) needs to know anything about a DAL.  This is a problem on multiple levels.  One: this is a violation of layering.  You don't truly have a data access layer or a business object layer if they both know about each other (the DAL produces entities, which in turn know about a "DAL" object--lower-level layers *cannot* know or be coupled to higher-level layers).  The repository is supposed to mediate between your BOL and DAL, what you've posted shows you're not implementing Repository if an entity is coupled to a DAL in some way

Comment: @PeterRitchie - DAL is a bit of a misnomer in this case.  The underlying system is LINQ to Object based.  LINQ to Objects populates objects that correspond to something very closely resembling the DB which is used in legacy apps.  We then have a BOL that wraps the objects produced by LINQ to Objects and adds business functionality to them.  The Repository is what is used to store actual data access queries and is what defines the LINQ queries used to get the objects, however we have to further work with the objects LINQ returns.  Since it is LINQ based, the LINQ objects must be changed.

Comment: The DAL implementations have an inheritance structure. That’s fine. But does that inheritance structure really need to be publically visible? Could you create a common DAL abstraction that meets the needs of both BaseDal and ChildDal and pass that type (interface or abstract class) around? The tight coupling between DAL and Entity doesn’t feel right.

Comment: @ErnieL - Unfortunately, there isn't a common abstract class that meets the needs of both Base and Child, however I switched to using a method hiding approach that simply approximates return type covariance.  This is basically the same as the proposed structure, however the interface is striped out to avoid having to make the DAL populated object reference public.

Comment: It seems it is possible to set a `ChildEntity._dal` to a `BaseDal`, which is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer here seems to be that it is a bad idea to have two parallel layers like this where one is providing retrieval for the other.  Generics on the return types of the one side can be used to meet a lot of the needs, but there are some pretty severe limitations on the functionality of the side using the generics due to co/contravarient issues associated with generics.